# Can Windows 7 run indefinately without being on a network?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

We would like to configure a very basic desktop PC delivered new with a Windows 7 operating system to operate in a completely isolated environment.  No network access.  What are the problems we should anticipate?

I have heard that we may run into Microsoft licensing issues, but as far as I can tell from *[This Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981009.aspx)*, as long as activation rules are followed, it should not be an issue.

Are there any other issues should we anticipate?

Comment: Where did you hear you will have problems?  It may be your source was confusing offline with a kms system.  My company uses a kms to build all machines including such always offline machines.  This means that a few years after the build it begins saying it is unlicensed .

Comment: @Ross - anecdotally.  A colleague uses _[Shuttle PCs](http://us.shuttle.com/)_ as part of his deliverable system, but loads Windows 7 from an install disk as part if his manufacturing process told me stories of licensing problems popping up at client sites, well after the OS install at the factory, and after he assumed the licensing process was completed satisfactorily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the problems we should anticipate?

You will have to activate the installation by phone.

> I have heard that we may run into Microsoft licensing issues

You heard incorrectly.  An internet connection is not required to use any version of Windows.

> Are there any other issues should we anticipate?

No

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might have to download required updates on an internet connected machine and install them manually by USB/CD/DVD.

Comment: @ryyker - No.  An Internet connection is not required to run Windows.  Updates can be downloaded then installed manually.